# Cannot mount FAT32 system as 777

Tags: mount, nfs, fat32

I am trying to mount an external HDD (fat32) with 777 permissions as I wish to share it via nfs on my local network.

I am mounting using the following command (and I have tried several variations):

sudo mount -t vfat -o user,umask=0000 /dev/sda1 /mnt/export

But it is still mounting the HDD as 755

Comment: you might want to have a look here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Manually_Mounting might help you